why in self-defined `drop` in rust, just 'touch' the buffer on heap is enough, rather than 'free' them?
I'm learning rust-lang these days, and digging into this blog: https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/third-final.html.
There has been a question of the Drop trait. On the page of I paster above, the author implements the Drop trait:
impl<T> Drop for List<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let mut head = self.head.take();
        while let Some(node) = head {
            if let Ok(mut node) = Rc::try_unwrap(node) {
                head = node.next.take();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

as the author says, he is deleting these nodes on heap.
But why he is just iterator on these nodes, instead of del them?
How rust knows to free these memory?


But why he is just iterator on these nodes, instead of del them?

Because there's no need to del them, the object can just be moved in scope then it will be dropped automatically.

How rust knows to free these memory?

There's nothing special to those types, so they'll have drop glue if T: Drop and Rust will know (how) to drop them, otherwise they're trivial and there's nothing to drop.
The reason why Drop is implemented here is the same as in 2.7: drop glue is recursive, but letting the compiler recursively drop all nodes of the linked list is slower than necessary, and if the list is long enough it might cause a stack overflow.

A nice illustration of this: std::mem::drop (the function you call if you want to explicitly drop something, for whatever reason) is just... an empty function. The argument immediately goes out of scope without being returned, causing it to get dropped.

@JoeClay Wow, you got me, really. Here drop() is just a normal function like others. Thx a lot.
